# If it takes less than a year to accelerate to the speed of light at 1g why will it take the Voyager 10,000 years to reach Alpha Centauri?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, acceleration, space-travel, interstellar-travel

Today I was doing my physics homework and there was a problem involving a space ship falling at 9.8 m/(s^2) to simulate gravity, and it asked how long would it take for the ship to reach to speed of light, and I calculated it to be just under a year. So if it takes less than a year to go to the speed of light at 9.8m/(s^2) to reach the speed of light and proximus centari is one light year away even with the consequences of relativity (which I understand in the abstract) why does it not take about six years to get to alpha centari, and why will it take Voyager (travelling at a much faster acceleration) so long, especially in space where there is no friction?

Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16983/discussion-on-question-by-the-floating-brain-if-it-takes-less-than-a-year-to-acc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the practical considerations, we can ignore the relativistic calculations for now.

The acceleration of a spacecraft depends on its mass (including unburned fuel it is carrying) and the engine it uses.  And the amount of time it can accelerate depends on how much fuel it has. Some of the total consequences of this can be found in the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation)

For modern rockets, accelerations near $1g$ require a high-thrust engine that consumes fuel rapidly.  The fuel capacity at such accelerations can be measured in minutes, not years.  The fuel is exhausted long before very high speeds are reached.

You can use the rocket equation to find out what it would take for a rocket to reach a particular speed (or more properly how much change in speed it can undergo).  If we take one of our most efficient engines (an ion thruster with an $I_{sp}$ of $10000\text{s}$) and see how much fuel is required to reach $0.1c$, then:

$$\Delta v = I_{sp}\,g_0\, \ln \frac{m_0}{m_1}$$
$$\ln \frac{m_0}{m_1} = \frac{\Delta v}{I_{sp}\,g_0}$$
$$\ln \frac{m_0}{m_1} = \frac{3.0\times 10^{7} \text{m/s}}{10000\text{s} (9.81\text{m/s}^2)}$$
$$\ln \frac{m_0}{m_1} = 305.6$$
$$\frac{m_0}{m_1} = 5\times 10^{132}$$

So even with one of today's fantastic engines, the craft would have to have a fuel mass that is over one hundred orders of magnitude greater than the non-fuel mass (the engines, the structure, the equipment, etc.)  That's simply not possible.

Comment: Thank you, but what about space having minimal friction (interstellar medium gas), why does the craft stop accelerating? Thank you again! :-D

Comment: It stops accelerating because it runs out of fuel. Newton's first law states that an object will move at a constant velocity unless acted on by an external force. The forces here would be gravity, the rocket fuel, and friction. Friction is excluded in BowlOfRed's analysis.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain In the comments above, you mention the example of an astronaut on the ISS throwing something. It stops accelerating the instant it leaves his hand.  After that, its acceleration is zero, which means exactly the same thing as saying that its velocity is constant.